# wget downloads index.html unnecessarily and halts batch script (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wget

I am having trouble with `wget64` on `Windows`:

```
@echo OFF
FOR /L %%i in (1, 1, 9999) DO (
cls
echo Downloading file %%i
wget64.exe -e robots=off --progress=bar --show-progress -r -np -nd -nc -HDfilepi.com --content-disposition -a wget.log ebooks.info/book/%%i/
)
```

`wget` will download `index.html` (which I feel is unnecessary), then it proceeds to the hosted file and downloads it if the file does not exist on the destination, but will fail to retrieve the `index.html` of the next book and start the next download.

Is it really necessary to download `index.html` and if that is the case, how can I tell `wget` to erase and download the new one every time?

> Disclaimer: I am only asking about the specific behaviour of wget, I
>   am not asking to help in the download script nor do I condone
>   illegally downloading files.

Comment: Yes, ebooks.info/book/%%i/ is the host that redirects to another host (filepi.com) where the file is located.

Comment: The URL `ebooks.info/book/%%i` doesn't exist.  Most redirect methods will have the a main body in their response, which is the (likely) reason why wget is fetching an index.html file.  A valid URL would be required to look into it further.

Comment: ebooks.info/book/%%i is just a placeholder, not the actual page as the page is blacklisted in stackoverflow. the real page is [IT eBooks](http://it-ebooks.info/book/1/)

Comment: In the future, you should indicate the use of a placeholder in your question.  Leaving it to be guessed at by people trying to help only wastes both of your time.

Comment: Did not think of that, will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overthinking this. Assuming that all the other files wget is retrieving are the correct ones, since you're using a FOR loop anyway, why not just delete index.html on each iteration like so:

```
@echo OFF
FOR /L %%i in (1, 1, 9999) DO (
cls
echo Downloading file %%i
wget64.exe -e robots=off --progress=bar --show-progress -r -np -nd -nc -HDfilepi.com --content-disposition -a wget.log ebooks.info/book/%%i/
if exist index.html del index.html
)
```